# What's the most idiomatic way to create a vector with a 1 at index i?

Tags: matlab, vector

In Matlab, suppose I would like to create a 0-vector of length `L`, except with a 1 at index `i`?

For example, something like:

```
>> mostlyzeros(6, 3)

ans =

     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

The purpose is so I can use it as a 'selection' vector which I'll multiply element-wise with another vector.

Comment: Presumably `mostlyzeros` would be a better name for this function...

Comment: @Cam Why would you ever want to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is this:

```
a = (1:N)==m;
```

where N>=m. Having said that, if you want to use the resulting vector as a "selection vector", I don't know why you'd multiply two vectors elementwise, as I would expect that to be relatively slow and inefficient. If you want to get a vector containing only the m-th value of vector v in the m-th position, this would be a more straightforward method:

```
b = ((1:N)==m)*v(m);
```

Although the most natural method would have to be this:

```
b(N)=0;
b(m)=v(m);
```

assuming that b isn't defined before this (if b is defined, you need to use zeros rather than just assigning the Nth value as zero - it has been my experience that creating a zero vector or matrix that didn't exist before that is most easily done by assigning the last element of it to be zero - it's also useful for extending a matrix or vector).

Comment: nice! this is what I was looking for.

Comment: +1: You're the only one that points out that "selection vectors" are not a native approach in MATLAB :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time thinking of anything more sensible than:

```
Vec = zeros(1, L);
Vec(i) = 1;
```

But I'd be happy to be proven wrong!

**UPDATE:** The one-liner solution provided by @GlenO is very neat! However, be aware that if efficiency is the chief criteria, then a few speed tests on my machine indicate that the simple method proposed in this answer and the other two answers is 3 or 4 times faster...

**NEXT UPDATE:** Ah! So that's what you mean by "selection vectors". @GlenO has given a good explanation of why for this operation a vector of ones and zeros is not idiomatic Matlab - however you choose to build it.

ps Try to avoid using `i` as a subscript, since it is actually a [matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/i.html).

Comment: +1 for execution time analysis, but I can't believe that one-line answer is 3-4 times slower... any idea why?

Comment: @Parag To perform the one-liner, Matlab must do the following 3 steps: 1) Build a vector of length `N` ie the `(1:N)` step, 2) find the element in that vector that is equal to `m` ie the `== m` step, and 3) build another vector of length `N` ie the `a = ` step. In contrast, our approach involves building only one vector of length `N`, and then changing a single element of that vector with a index that is known *a priori*. From the computer's perspective that is much simpler. ps cheers for the +1

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it, another one-liner:

```
function [out] = mostlyzeros(idx, L)
out([L, idx]) = [0 1];
```

Comment: a better way would be `out([L,idx]) = [0 1];`

Answer (score 1):

I can think of:

```
function mostlyones(m,n)

mat=zeros(1,m);
mat(n)=1;
```

Also, one thing to note. In MATLAB, index starts from one and not from zero. So your function call should have been `mostlyzeros(6,3)`

Comment: @ColinTBowers Thanks anyway, but I really don't deserve an upvote for such a simple answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create a zero-vector and change whatever value you like to one:

```
function zeroWithOne(int numOfZeros, int pos)
a = zeros(numOfZeros,1);
a(pos) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one line option, which should be fast is:

`vec = sparse(1, ii, 1, 1, L);`